# How to using BigQuery PARSE_TIMESTAMP parse DateTime concat with underscore?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a time stemp formated as a string like this: `2022_05_26_13_52_05` which is format as `YYYY_MM_DD_hh_mm_ss` how can I use BigQuery PARSE_TIMESTAMP to parse it? I try it with

```
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y_%m_%d_%I_%M_%S", "2022_05_26_13_52_05") from `Something.test.my_table_name_*`
```

It fails at: `Failed to parse input string "2022_05_26_13_52_05"`, but if I only parse `PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y_%m_%d", "2022_05_26")`. It works perfectly fine. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try below instead

```
PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S", "2022_05_26_13_52_05")
```

with result

```
2022-05-26 13:52:05 UTC
```

Comment: Hi Mikhail, it works perfectly fine. Looks like, I put %I for wrong hour format. Thanks a lot

Comment: sure. yes - this was the only wrong piece :o)